# Calling a bash script from PHP to generate another script

Tags: php, bash

I am writing an application which takes text input from the user to generate a text file. A bash script, which takes the generated text file as input should generate another script as output.

I tried using exec command but I am not sure if it works. I want something like this:

```
exec('generate.sh input.txt generated.sh');
```

generate.sh takes two inputs:

1. `input.txt` file - has user input from PHP page(text separated by '\n')
2. `generated.sh` - name of the generated file(to be generated by 'generate.sh').

How can I execute the bash script from PHP to get the above output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: generate.sh also would need to be in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole argument to exec needs to be a string like this:

```
exec('generate.sh input.txt generated.sh');
```

Comment: Is generate.sh running?  Do you need to reference it as `('/path/to/generate.sh /path/to/input.txt /path/to/generated.sh')` or is their a system alias in place for the executable and the script understand what directories the input/output goes to?  Are the file permissions set correctly for the executable (has x bit set) and for the input/output directories and files?

Comment: You are right. I didnt set the x bit for all the files. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$generate = '/path/to/generate.sh';
$input = '/path/to/input.txt';
$generated = '/path/to/generated.sh';

if(file_exists($generate))
{
    chmod($generate, 0755);
    if(file_exists($input))
    {
        exec($generate.' '.$input.' '.$generated);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Input file not found: ".$input."<br />";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Generate file not found: ".$generate."<br />";
}
```

Furthermore you can also consider system(), shell_exec(), passthru() or proc_open() to execute external commands.